# wxpython custom panel reused in a frame showing unusual

Tags: wxpython

See the codes as below, my WxPython version is 4.0.1, I want to customing a component based wxPanel and reusing it in a wxFrame. The showing of second object was unusual, I couldn't find any error of my codes ,there is must something I don't know, someone help, thank you very much!

```
import wx

class ListPl(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, size=(200, 200), pos=(0, 0), index=-1):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, pos=pos, size=(100, 100))
        self.t1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Test1")
        self.t2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Test2")
        self.t3 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Test3")
        self.t1.SetBackgroundColour("RED")
        self.t2.SetBackgroundColour("YELLOW")
        self.t3.SetBackgroundColour("BLUE")

        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vbox.Add(self.t1, proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.vbox.Add(self.t2, proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.vbox.Add(self.t3, proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(self.vbox)
        self.SetBackgroundColour((size[0], size[1], 120+index*100))

import wx
from ListPl import ListPl


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, size=(960, 639)):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="test", size=size)
        self.lp = ListPl(self, size=(100, 100), index=1)
        self.lp2 = ListPl(self, size=(100, 100), index=2)
        rs = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        rs.Add(self.lp, flag=wx.ALL)
        rs.Add(self.lp2, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(rs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    TestFrame(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[test.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Vfa.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the environment that you are running this under, so try running it directly from the command line. It should work.
Although, your last line in `ListPl.py` will overrride the background colours that you set on the statictext items. Instead try changing `ListPl.py` to the following:

```
import wx

class ListPl(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, size=(200, 200), pos=(0, 0), index=-1):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, pos=pos, size=(100, 100))
        self.t1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Test1")
        self.t2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Test2")
        self.t3 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Test3")
        self.t1.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
        self.t2.SetForegroundColour(wx.YELLOW)
        self.t3.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLUE)

        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vbox.Add(self.t1, proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.vbox.Add(self.t2, proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.vbox.Add(self.t3, proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(self.vbox)
        self.SetBackgroundColour((size[0], size[1], 120+index*100))
```

[image]